# Chatbot in Dialogflow+WhatsApp triggering intents without user input

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm having a problem finalizing a chatbot in Dialogflow and I don't know how to solve it.

The chatbot project includes the use of three platforms: Dialogflow + JivoChat (for human service) + Twilio (WhatsApp integration).

The chatbot in question was built with the inputs being numbers, that is

- 1- option 1
- 2- option 2
- 3- option 3

When the flow reaches the end, the chatbot instead of waiting for the user's response to define what action to take next, it chooses the option according to the previous response. In case that response does not exist (for example, the user entered 6, but the options only go up to 3) the fallback intent is called.

Has anyone had this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using dialogflow-es or dialogflow-cx? If you are using dialogflow-cx you can add the sequence order of actions which will help you with your issue. If you are using dialogflow-es its a bit flat on that regard and intents are mixed up, I will recommend to allocate properly your parameters. Also, can you share your code or url with the agent details.

Comment: If you want to parse the input from the user that its invalid you can just have an intent that can catch the out-of-place digit and just provide a default response for it. Preventing the fallback intent to be called.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.